# How can I change the colour of the Name Methods on Intellij?

Tags: java, colors, fonts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gOZ5.png)

How can I change the colour of "addition", I can't find where to do it

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#semantic-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Preferences.. -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Java(or other languages) -> Methods -> choose a color and then apply